# Problem exporting contour lines between QGIS and Rhino (or AutoCAD)

Tags: qgis, raster, export, contour, scale

I am a French student studying architecture in Mexico. Currently, I am trying to retrieve contour lines in QGIS from a raster (.tiff) to export them to Rhino 7.

Processes:
I import my raster file (it is well scaled), I extract the contour lines, then I use the "v to 3d" plug-in which I think I define well. I get a layer called 3D, and when I check in the attribute table each of my curves has a well-informed height. The problem occurs when I export this layer in DXF (I tick the Z box). When I check in AutoCAD or Rhino 7 the layers are either too far apart or stacked on the same layer. I don't understand.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE. Would you be able to share some screenshots illustrating what you see in AutoCAD or Rhino to help others figure out what the issue might be?